# In Juju, what command to use for accessing environment settings from within a hook script?

Tags: juju

My specific case is for getting the amazon EC2 authentication information stored in the environments.yaml.
I am aware of the get-constraints command available in recent Juju builds. Can this be used to access this information?

Comment: Try referring here http://jujucharms.com/docs/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the information you need as config parameters for the charm.

To do this, you'd:

- add parameter names into the charm's config.yaml file
- either pass the keys in as a `--config` part of the `juju deploy` command or alternatively using the `juju set` command
- read the keys from the charm hooks using the `config-get` command

Comment: I am automating the juju commands so it is more suitable to  use --config switch than calling set .Also I need the parameters within in the install and xxx-relation-added hooks.

Answer (score 1):

At this time you can not access Environment varaibables. If your charm requires authentication information you'll need to add it as a configuration option for that Charm (Charms should be designed to deploy on all stacks, so not every provider will have something like an ec2-authentication key). If you require AWS services in your charm consider exposing those in the configuration with something like this:

```
options:
  aws-public-key:
    type: string
    default: ""
    description: Amazon Public Key for S3
  aws-secret-key:
    type: string
    default: ""
    description: Amazon Secret Key for S3
  s3-bucket:
    type: string
    default: ""
    description: Amazon S3 Bucket
```

So these would be set using the `juju set`command and would be available in the config_changed hook via `config-get`

- [Service Configuration](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/drafts/service-config.html)

Comment: I have used the config.yaml to preset the variables